# Unable to install pytorch in conda due to setuptools is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda, setuptools

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

Here is the error I encountered

```
 RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

However, setuptools is not found in
`conda list`. What should I do?

> ## Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
>
> _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36he6757f0_0
>   _r-mutex                  1.0.0                     mro_2    r
>   _tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu    anaconda absl-py                   0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
>   alabaster                 0.7.10           py36hcd07829_0 anaconda
>   custom           py36h363777c_0 anaconda-client           1.6.5
>   py36hd36550c_0 anaconda-navigator        1.6.9
>   py36hc720852_0 anaconda-project          0.8.0
>   py36h8b3bf89_0 asn1crypto                0.22.0
>   py36h8e79faa_1 astor                     0.7.1
>   pypi_0    pypi astroid                   1.5.3
>   py36h9d85297_0 astropy                   2.0.2
>   py36h06391c4_4 babel                     2.5.0
>   pypi_0    pypi backports                 1.0
>   py36h81696a8_1 backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0
>   py36h79ab834_2 beautifulsoup4            4.6.0
>   py36hd4cc5e8_1 bitarray                  0.8.1
>   py36h6af124b_0 bkcharts                  0.2
>   py36h7e685f7_0 blas                      1.0
>   mkl blaze                     0.11.3           py36h8a29ca5_0 bleach
>   2.0.0            py36h0a7e3d6_0 bokeh                     0.12.10          py36h0be3b39_0 boto                      2.48.0
>   py36h1a776d2_1 bottleneck                1.2.1
>   py36hd119dfa_0 bzip2                     1.0.6
>   vc14hdec8e7a_1  [vc14] ca-certificates           2018.11.29
>   ha4d7672_0    conda-forge cachecontrol              0.12.3
>   py36hfe50d7b_0 certifi                   2018.11.29
>   py36_1000    conda-forge cffi                      1.10.0
>   py36hae3d1b5_1 chardet                   3.0.4
>   py36h420ce6e_1 click                     6.7
>   py36hec8c647_0 cloudpickle               0.4.0
>   py36h639d8dc_0 clyent                    1.2.2
>   py36hb10d595_1 colorama                  0.3.9
>   py36h029ae33_0 comtypes                  1.1.2
>   py36heb9b3d1_0 conda                     4.6.8
>   py36_0    conda-forge conda-build               3.0.27
>   py36h309a530_0 conda-env                 2.6.0
>   h36134e3_1 conda-verify              2.0.0            py36h065de53_0
>   console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3 contextlib2 
>   0.5.5            py36he5d52c0_0 crowdposetools            2.0                      pypi_0    pypi cryptography              2.5
>   py36h74b6da3_1    conda-forge cudatoolkit               9.0
>   1    anaconda cudnn                     7.1.4
>   cuda9.0_0    anaconda curl                      7.55.1
>   vc14hdaba4a4_3  [vc14] cycler                    0.10.0
>   py36h009560c_0 cython                    0.26.1
>   py36h18049ac_0 cytoolz                   0.8.2
>   py36h547e66e_0 dask                      0.17.5
>   py36_0 dask-core                 0.17.5                   py36_0
>   datashape                 0.5.4            py36h5770b85_0 decorator
>   4.1.2            py36he63a57b_0 distlib                   0.2.5            py36h51371be_0 distributed               1.21.8
>   py36_0 docker-pycreds            0.3.0                    pypi_0
>   pypi docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
>   entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2 et_xmlfile
>   1.0.1            py36h3d2d736_0 fastcache                 1.0.2            py36hffdae1b_0 filelock                  2.0.12
>   py36hd7ddd41_0 flask                     0.12.2
>   py36h98b5e8f_0 flask-cors                3.0.3
>   py36h8a3855d_0 font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37
>   h6964260_0 font-ttf-inconsolata      2.001                hcb22688_0
>   font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.030                h7457263_0
>   font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h8b1ccd4_0
>   fonts-anaconda            1                    h8fa9717_0 freetype
>   2.9.1             h5db478b_1005    conda-forge gast                      0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi geos                      3.6.2                he025d50_3    conda-forge get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0 gevent                    1.2.2            py36h342a76c_0 glob2                     0.5
>   py36h11cc1bd_1 google-images-download    2.4.2
>   pypi_0    pypi greenlet                  0.4.12
>   py36ha00ad21_0 grpcio                    1.14.1
>   pypi_0    pypi h5py                      2.8.0
>   py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge hdf5                      1.10.1
>   vc14hb361328_0  [vc14] heapdict                  1.0.0
>   py36h21fa5f4_0 html5lib                  0.999999999
>   py36ha09b1f3_0 icc_rt                    2017.0.4
>   h97af966_0 icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0 
>   [vc14] idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
>   imageio                   2.2.0            py36had6c2d2_0 imagesize
>   0.7.1            py36he29f638_0 imutils                   0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi intel-openmp              2018.0.0
>   hcd89f80_7 ipykernel                 4.6.1            py36hbb77b34_0
>   ipython                   6.1.0            py36h236ecc8_1
>   ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0 ipywidgets
>   7.0.0            py36h2e74ada_0 isort                     4.2.15           py36h6198cc5_0 itsdangerous              0.24
>   py36hb6c5a24_1 jdcal                     1.3
>   py36h64a5255_0 jedi                      0.10.2
>   py36hed927a0_0 jinja2                    2.9.6
>   py36h10aa3a0_1 jpeg                      9b
>   vc14h4d7706e_1  [vc14] jsonschema                2.6.0
>   py36h7636477_0 jupyter                   1.0.0
>   py36h422fd7e_2 jupyter_client            5.1.0
>   py36h9902a9a_0 jupyter_console           5.2.0
>   py36h6d89b47_1 jupyter_core              4.3.0
>   py36h511e818_0 jupyterlab                0.27.0
>   py36h34cc53b_2 jupyterlab_launcher       0.4.0
>   py36h22c3ccf_0 keras                     2.2.4
>   0    anaconda keras-applications        1.0.6
>   py36_0    anaconda keras-base                2.2.4
>   py36_0    anaconda keras-preprocessing       1.0.5
>   py36_0    anaconda kiwisolver                1.0.1
>   py36he980bc4_1002    conda-forge kmodes                    0.9
>   pypi_0    pypi krb5                      1.16.3
>   h038dc86_1000    conda-forge lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1
>   py36hd1c21d2_0 libcurl                   7.64.0
>   h4496350_2    conda-forge libgpuarray               0.7.6
>   hfa6e2cd_1003    conda-forge libiconv                  1.15
>   vc14h29686d3_5  [vc14] libpng                    1.6.36
>   h7602738_1000    conda-forge libprotobuf               3.6.1
>   h1a1b453_1000    conda-forge libssh2                   1.8.0
>   vc14hcf584a9_2  [vc14] libtiff                   4.0.9
>   hf1753bf_1    conda-forge libxml2                   2.9.4
>   vc14h8fd0f11_5  [vc14] libxslt                   1.1.29
>   vc14hf85b8d4_5  [vc14] llvmlite                  0.20.0
>   py36_0 locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1
>   lockfile                  0.12.2           py36h0468280_0 lxml
>   4.1.0            py36h0dcd83c_0 lzo                       2.10             vc14h0a64fa6_1  [vc14] m2-bash                   4.3.042
>   5 m2-gcc-libs               5.3.0                         4 m2-heimdal
>   1.5.3                        10 m2-heimdal-libs           1.5.3                        10 m2-icu                    56.1                          2
>   m2-libcrypt               1.3                           2 m2-libdb
>   5.3.28                        3 m2-libedit                3.1                    20150326 m2-libopenssl             1.0.2.g                       2
>   m2-libreadline            6.3.008                       8 m2-libsqlite
>   3.10.0.0                      2 m2-msys2-runtime          2.5.0.17080.65c939c               3 m2-ncurses                6.0.20160220                  2 m2-openssh                7.1p2                         2 m2-openssl                1.0.2.g                       2 m2-zlib
>   1.2.8                         4 m2w64-bzip2               1.0.6                         6 m2w64-diffutils           3.3.2                         2
>   m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
>   m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
>   m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7 m2w64-gmp
>   6.1.0                         2 m2w64-grep                2.24                          2 m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
>   m2w64-pcre                8.38                          2
>   m2w64-wineditline         2.101                         5 m2w64-zlib
>   1.2.8                        10 mako                      1.0.7                      py_1    conda-forge markdown                  2.6.11
>   py_0    conda-forge markupsafe                1.0
>   py36h0e26971_1 matplotlib                3.0.2
>   py36_1002    conda-forge matplotlib-base           3.0.2
>   py36h3e3dc42_1002    conda-forge mccabe                    0.6.1
>   py36hb41005a_1 menuinst                  1.4.14
>   py36_1000    conda-forge mistune                   0.7.4
>   py36h4874169_0 mkl                       2018.0.0
>   h36b65af_4 mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h57e144c_4
>   mpmath                    0.19             py36he326802_2 mro-base
>   3.5.1                         3    r mro-base_impl             3.5.1                         0    r msgpack                   0.5.6                    pypi_0
>   pypi msgpack-python            0.4.8            py36h58b1e9d_0
>   msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
>   multipledispatch          0.4.9            py36he44c36e_0
>   navigator-updater         0.1.0            py36h8a7b86b_0 nbconvert
>   5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0 nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0 networkx                  2.0
>   py36hff991e3_0 nltk                      3.2.4
>   py36hd0e0a39_0 nose                      1.3.7
>   py36h1c3779e_2 notebook                  5.0.0
>   py36hd9fbf6f_2 npm                       0.1.1
>   pypi_0    pypi numba                     0.35.0
>   np112py36_0 numexpr                   2.6.2            py36h7ca04dc_1
>   numpy                     1.14.5                   pypi_0    pypi
>   numpydoc                  0.7.0            py36ha25429e_0 odo
>   0.5.1            py36h7560279_0 olefile                   0.44             py36h0a7bdd2_0 open3d                    0+unknown
>   pypi_0    pypi opencv-contrib-python     3.4.1.15
>   pypi_0    pypi opencv-python             4.0.0.21
>   pypi_0    pypi openpyxl                  2.4.8
>   py36hf3b77f6_1 openssl                   1.0.2r
>   hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge optional-django           0.1.0
>   pypi_0    pypi packaging                 16.8
>   py36ha0986f6_1 pandas                    0.23.0
>   py36h830ac7b_0 pandoc                    1.19.2.1
>   hb2460c7_1 pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
>   partd                     0.3.8            py36hc8e763b_0 path.py
>   10.3.1           py36h3dd8b46_0 pathlib2                  2.3.0            py36h7bfb78b_0 patsy                     0.4.1
>   py36h42cefec_0 pep8                      1.7.0
>   py36h0f3d67a_0 pickleshare               0.7.4
>   py36h9de030f_0 pillow                    5.2.0
>   py36h08bbbbd_0 pip                       19.0.3
>   pypi_0    pypi pkginfo                   1.4.1
>   py36hb0f9cfa_1 plotly                    2.7.0
>   pypi_0    pypi ply                       3.10
>   py36h1211beb_0 progress                  1.3
>   py36hbeca8d3_0 prompt_toolkit            1.0.15
>   py36h60b8f86_0 protobuf                  3.6.1
>   pypi_0    pypi psutil                    5.4.0
>   py36h4e662fb_0 py                        1.4.34
>   py36ha4aca3a_1 pyclustering              0.8.0
>   pypi_0    pypi pycocotools               2.0
>   pypi_0    pypi pycodestyle               2.3.1
>   py36h7cc55cd_0 pycosat                   0.6.3
>   py36h413d8a4_0 pycparser                 2.18
>   py36hd053e01_1 pycrypto                  2.6.1
>   py36he68e6e2_1 pycurl                    7.43.0.2
>   py36h74b6da3_0 pydotplus                 2.0.2
>   pypi_0    pypi pyflakes                  1.6.0
>   py36h0b975d6_0 pygments                  2.2.0
>   py36hb010967_0 pygpu                     0.7.6
>   py36h452e1ab_1000    conda-forge pylint                    1.7.4
>   py36ha4e6ded_0 pyodbc                    4.0.17
>   py36h0006bc2_0 pyopenssl                 17.2.0
>   py36h15ca2fc_0 pyparsing                 2.2.0
>   py36h785a196_1 pyqt                      5.6.0
>   py36_2 pyreadline                2.1                   py36_1000
>   conda-forge pysocks                   1.6.7            py36h698d350_1
>   pytables                  3.4.2            py36h71138e3_2 pytesseract 
>   0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi pytest                    3.2.1            py36h753b05e_1 python                    3.6.3                h9e2ca53_1 python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h509ddcb_1
>   python-graphviz           0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi pytz
>   2017.2           py36h05d413f_1 pywavelets                0.5.2            py36hc649158_0 pywin32                   221
>   py36h9c10281_0 pyyaml                    3.12
>   py36h1d1928f_1 pyzmq                     16.0.2
>   py36h38c27d9_2 qt                        5.6.2
>   vc14_1    conda-forge qtawesome                 0.4.4
>   py36h5aa48f6_0 qtconsole                 4.3.1
>   py36h99a29a9_0 qtpy                      1.3.1
>   py36hb8717c5_0 r-assertthat              0.2.0
>   mro351_0    r r-backports               1.1.2
>   mro351_0    r r-base64enc               0.1_3
>   mro351_0    r r-bh                      1.66.0_1
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-bindr                   0.1.1
>   mro351_0    r r-bindrcpp                0.2.2
>   mro351_0    r r-bit                     1.1_14
>   mro351_0    r r-bit64                   0.9_7
>   mro351_0    r r-bitops                  1.0_6
>   mro351_0    r r-blob                    1.1.1
>   mro351_0    r r-broom                   0.5.0
>   mro351_0    r r-catools                 1.17.1.1
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-cellranger              1.1.0
>   mro351_0    r r-cli                     1.0.0
>   mro351_0    r r-config                  0.3
>   mro351_0    r r-crayon                  1.3.4
>   mro351_0    r r-curl                    3.2
>   mro351_0    r r-dbi                     1.0.0
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-dbplyr                  1.2.2
>   mro351_0    r r-digest                  0.6.15
>   mro351_0    r r-dplyr                   0.7.6
>   mro351_0    r r-evaluate                0.11
>   mro351_0    r r-fansi                   0.2.3
>   mro351_0    r r-forcats                 0.3.0
>   mro351_0    r r-glue                    1.3.0
>   mro351_0    r r-haven                   1.1.2
>   mro351_0    r r-highr                   0.7
>   mro351_0    r r-hms                     0.4.2
>   mro351_0    r r-htmltools               0.3.6
>   mro351_0    r r-htmlwidgets             1.2
>   mro351_0    r r-httpuv                  1.4.5
>   mro351_0    r r-httr                    1.3.1
>   mro351_0    r r-jsonlite                1.5
>   mro351_0    r r-knitr                   1.20
>   mro351_0    r r-later                   0.7.3
>   mro351_0    r r-lattice                 0.20_35
>   mro351_0    r r-lazyeval                0.2.1
>   mro351_0    r r-magrittr                1.5
>   mro351_0    r r-markdown                0.8
>   mro351_0    r r-mime                    0.5
>   mro351_0    r r-miniui                  0.1.1.1
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-mongolite               1.6
>   mro351_0    r r-nlme                    3.1_137
>   mro351_0    r r-odbc                    1.1.6
>   mro351_0    r r-openssl                 1.0.2
>   mro351_0    r r-packrat                 0.4.9_3
>   mro351_0    r r-pillar                  1.3.0
>   mro351_0    r r-pkgconfig               2.0.1
>   mro351_0    r r-pki                     0.1_5.1
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-plogr                   0.2.0
>   mro351_0    r r-plyr                    1.8.4
>   mro351_0    r r-prettyunits             1.0.2
>   mro351_0    r r-profvis                 0.3.5
>   mro351_0    r r-promises                1.0.1
>   mro351_0    r r-purrr                   0.2.5
>   mro351_0    r r-r6                      2.2.2
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-rappdirs                0.3.1
>   mro351_0    r r-rcpp                    0.12.18
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-rcurl                   1.95_4.11
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-readr                   1.1.1
>   mro351_0    r r-readxl                  1.1.0
>   mro351_0    r r-rematch                 1.0.1
>   mro351_0    r r-reshape2                1.4.3
>   mro351_0    r r-revoutils               11.0.0
>   mro351_0    r r-revoutilsmath           11.0.0
>   mro351_0    r r-rjava                   0.9_9
>   mro343h889e2dd_0    r r-rjdbc                   0.2_7.1
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-rjsonio                 1.3_0
>   mro351hf348343_0    r r-rlang                   0.2.1
>   mro351_0    r r-rmarkdown               1.10
>   mro351_0    r r-rprojroot               1.3_2
>   mro351_0    r r-rsconnect               0.8.8
>   mro351_0    r r-rstudioapi              0.7
>   mro351_0    r r-shiny                   1.1.0
>   mro351_0    r r-sourcetools             0.1.7
>   mro351_0    r r-sparklyr                0.8.4
>   mro351_0    r r-stringi                 1.1.7
>   mro351_0    r r-stringr                 1.3.1
>   mro351_0    r r-tibble                  1.4.2
>   mro351_0    r r-tidyr                   0.8.1
>   mro351_0    r r-tidyselect              0.2.4
>   mro351_0    r r-tinytex                 0.6
>   mro351_0    r r-utf8                    1.1.4
>   mro351_0    r r-withr                   2.1.2
>   mro351_0    r r-xfun                    0.3
>   mro351_0    r r-xml2                    1.2.0
>   mro351_0    r r-xtable                  1.8_2
>   mro351_0    r r-yaml                    2.2.0
>   mro351_0    r requests                  2.18.4
>   py36h4371aae_1 rope                      0.10.5
>   py36hcaf5641_0 rstudio                   1.1.456
>   vc14h1ad3211_1  [vc14]  r ruamel_yaml               0.11.14
>   py36h9b16331_2 scikit-image              0.13.0
>   py36h6dffa3f_1 scikit-learn              0.19.1
>   py36h53aea1b_0 scipy                     1.0.0
>   py36h1260518_0 seaborn                   0.8.0
>   py36h62cb67c_0 selenium                  3.14.1
>   pypi_0    pypi shapely                   1.6.4
>   py36hc90234e_1000    conda-forge simplegeneric             0.8.1
>   py36heab741f_0 singledispatch            3.4.0.3
>   py36h17d0c80_0 sip                       4.19.8
>   py36h6538335_1000    conda-forge six                       1.11.0
>   py36h4db2310_1 slidingwindow             0.0.13
>   pypi_0    pypi snowballstemmer           1.2.1
>   py36h763602f_0 sortedcollections         0.5.3
>   py36hbefa0ab_0 sortedcontainers          1.5.7
>   py36ha90ac20_0 sphinx                    1.6.3
>   py36h9bb690b_0 sphinxcontrib             1.0
>   py36hbbac3d2_1 sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1
>   py36hb5e5916_1 spyder                    3.2.4
>   py36h8845eaa_0 sqlalchemy                1.1.13
>   py36h5948d12_0 sqlite                    3.26.0
>   hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge statsmodels               0.8.0
>   py36h6189b4c_0 sympy                     1.1.1
>   py36h96708e0_0 tblib                     1.3.2
>   py36h30f5020_0 tensorboard               1.11.0
>   py36he025d50_0    anaconda tensorflow                1.11.0
>   gpu_py36h5dc63e2_0    anaconda tensorflow-base           1.11.0
>   gpu_py36h6e53903_0    anaconda tensorflow-gpu            1.11.0
>   h0d30ee6_0    anaconda termcolor                 1.1.0
>   pypi_0    pypi testpath                  0.3.1
>   py36h2698cfe_0 theano                    1.0.3
>   py36_0    conda-forge tk                        8.6.9
>   hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge toolz                     0.8.2
>   py36he152a52_0 tornado                   4.5.2
>   py36h57f6048_0 traitlets                 4.3.2
>   py36h096827d_0 typing                    3.6.2
>   py36hb035bda_0 unicodecsv                0.14.1
>   py36h6450c06_0 urllib3                   1.22
>   py36h276f60a_0 vc                        14
>   0    conda-forge vs2015_runtime            15.5.2
>   3 vs2015_win-64             14.0.25123           h17c34da_3 wcwidth
>   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0 webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1 websocket-client          0.53.0
>   pypi_0    pypi werkzeug                  0.12.2
>   py36h866a736_0 wheel                     0.29.0
>   py36h6ce6cde_1 widgetsnbextension        3.0.2
>   py36h364476f_1 win_inet_pton             1.0.1
>   py36he67d7fd_1 win_unicode_console       0.5
>   py36hcdbd4b5_0 wincertstore              0.2
>   py36h7fe50ca_0 wrapt                     1.10.11
>   py36he5f5981_0 xlrd                      1.1.0
>   py36h1cb58dc_1 xlsxwriter                1.0.2
>   py36hf723b7d_0 xlwings                   0.11.4
>   py36hd3cf94d_0 xlwt                      1.3.0
>   py36h1a4751e_0 yaml                      0.1.7
>   vc14hb31d195_1  [vc14] zict                      0.1.3
>   py36h2d8e73e_0 zlib                      1.2.11
>   vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]

Comment: Install `pytorch` in an environment, rather than in the base environment where `conda` is installed

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment, try to create an environment and install pytorch.
I had followed the below steps and it works for me.

1. Create a conda environment using the command :

   `conda create -n my_env python=3.6`
2. Activate the environment.

   `source activate my_env`
3. Install pytorch

   `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch`

Note: my_env is the name of your enivironment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: create a new environment faces the same issue of `setuptools`.